# How to convert []byte data to uint16 in go?

Tags: go, types

I have the following hex data: `0xB01B`; its `45083` as uint16; how do I convert this to uint16 in go?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the [`encoding/binary`](//godoc.org/encoding/binary) package:

```
import (
   "encoding/binary"
)

data := []byte{0xB0, 0x1B}
val := binary.BigEndian.Uint16(data)
```

https://play.golang.org/p/wHW8KDgls9

Answer (score 0):

Another option is `ReadUint16`:

```
package main
import "golang.org/x/crypto/cryptobyte"

func main() {
   s := cryptobyte.String{0xB0, 0x1B}
   var n uint16
   s.ReadUint16(&n)
   println(n == 45083)
}
```

https://godocs.io/golang.org/x/crypto/cryptobyte#String.ReadUint16